# Fade in and Fade out watermark on a video every x seconds/minutes for y seconds/minutes using FFMPEG

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I would like to know if there is a to fade in and fade out watermark on a video every x seconds/minutes for y seconds/minutes using FFMPEG. I have tried the -filter_complex to see if it can help, but I haven't any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the loop filter.

```
ffmpeg -i video -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex
        "[1]trim=0:30,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,
            loop=999:750:0,setpts=N/25/TB[w];
         [0][w]overlay=shortest=1"  out.mp4
```

First, the logo image stream is trimmed to a duration of `x` seconds, here 30. Then a 1-second fade-in and fade-out is applied. The fade-out starts at `y-1` seconds, here 9. That result is looped 999 times - use a number sufficient to span the length of the video. Since I've trimmed a 30-second segment, the size of the segment to be looped is `duration x framerate`, here `30 x 25` = `750`. The loop starts from the beginning frame `0`. Finally, the loop filter doesn't sanitize the timestamps, so setpts is added to produce a monotonic series.

The stream is then overlaid on the video.

Comment: Gyan, what could I add in parameters to make these steps: fade in a random (x,y) position of the video, fade out after 3 seconds, wait 1 minute and loop?