# How to add watermark in bottom right corner with fade in/out with time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to know how to add the watermark in right corner with fade in fade out with start and end time

I have used the below command

```
ffmpeg -i 1920.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]trim=0:30,fade=in:st=4:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,loop=999:750:0,setpts=N/25/TB[w];[0][w]overlay=W-w-10:10" 1920i4.mp4 2>&1
```

The above cmd output is water mark shows at left top corner with fade in start time is 4 sec and fade out end time is 9sec but need bottom right watermark

Reffer the below URL

[Fade in and Fade out watermark on a video every x seconds/minutes for y seconds/minutes using FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/questions/1118354/fade-in-and-fade-out-watermark-on-a-video-every-x-seconds-minutes-for-y-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Change `overlay=W-w-10:10` to `overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10`

See [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).